# Cats can not resolve symbol |@|

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-cats

I have the following code, which I got from here: http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/06/10/an-introduction-to-cats.html.

```
import cats.data.Xor
import cats.data.{Validated, Xor}
import cats.syntax.apply._ // For |@| syntax
import cats.std.list._
val v1: ValidatedR = valid(1)
val v2: ValidatedR = invalid(List("Accumulates this"))
val v3: ValidatedR = invalid(List("And this"))
(v1 |@| v2 |@| v3) map { _ + _ + _ }
```

However, I'm getting:

```
Cannot resolve symbol |@|
```

My `build.sbt`:

```
val snapshots = "Sonatype Snapshots"  at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

val algebraVersion = "0.2.0-SNAPSHOT"
val catsVersion    = "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

val algebra    = "org.spire-math" %% "algebra" % algebraVersion
val algebraStd = "org.spire-math" %% "algebra-std" % algebraVersion

val cats       = "org.spire-math" %% "cats-core" % catsVersion
val catsStd    = "org.spire-math" %% "cats-std" % catsVersion

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++=
  Seq(
    algebra, algebraStd,
    cats, catsStd
  )

resolvers += snapshots
```

Is there anything else that I should be importing or using?

Comment: The import is now `cats.syntax.cartesian._`, also the `List` instances can now be imported with `cats.instances.list._`. Probably the easiest if you get started is to just use `import cats.implicits._`.

Comment: When importing `cats.syntax.cartesian._` I'm getting `Error:(2, 22) object cartesian is not a member of package cats.syntax`
                    ^

Comment: Are you using the Cats version mentioned in the article ?

Comment: Yes. I updated the post to show my `build.sbt` file.

Comment: You can probably save yourself some pain (encountering similar issues) by using the most recent version of Cats (0.8.1). The links to the Cats documentation I gave in my answer, might be a good starting point. In the [Cats gitter channel](https://gitter.im/typelevel/cats) you can always find a lot of people willing to help by the way.

Answer (score 6):

The example is a little dated. A few things have changed since then :

- `|@|` is now provided by the `Cartesian` type class compared to the `Apply` type class before.
- The imports for types like `Option`, `List`, ... from the Scala standard library have been renamed from `cats.std.xxx` to `cats.instances.xxx`.
- The  latest version of Cats doesn't have the `Xor` data type any more, but uses the `scala.util.Either` data type instead.

Like I mentioned in my comment, it is easier to use the "uber" import `cats.implicits._`.

For some similar (and up to date) examples you could take a look at the Cats documentation of [`Validated`](http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html) and [`Either`](http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/either.html).

Comment: Beware: importing implicits in bulk is easier but can make the compilation more expensive. Precise imports of implicits are usually preferable.

Comment: You have a point @GabrielePetronella, but wouldn't you concur they are a little more advanced and not as beginner friendly (leading to issues like this) ? The Cats documentation also tries to use the "uber" import everywhere, see [#1026](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/1026).

Comment: Yes, I agree. My point is: uber imports come with a cost which may not be evident, so it's probably worth a  mention m

Comment: Or people may end up thinking that libraries like cats "male the compilation time slow" while a more accurate handling of imports can help a lot